# Orientation not changing to portrait, iOS game

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Am new to Xcode, using version 8, and have a small game done.

The problem I am facing is that the orientation is in landscape, which I can't get to portrait, in the simulator and on device.

Tried the following :

1. Changing Device Orientation under Deployment Info to Portrait,
2. Adding 'Portrait' under Supported interface orientations in the Info.plist file.

Maybe I m missing out on something that I may have overlooked. Could somebody shed some light on this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish, do you want your app to support portrait orientation only, or do you want it to support multiple orientations ?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Sorry, had a mistake in my question. Need to set the orientation as 'Portrait'. Its displays currently in the 'Landscape' mode, which I can't get changed to 'Portrait'.

Comment: did you try disabling all orientations in deployment info and keep the portrait only ?

Comment: Yes, I did that. Doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just found this out. I am using cocos2D framework, which has the 'startUpOptions' Dictionary object (in AppDelegate.m) that need to be specified if the game needs to be in 'Portrait' mode thus:

```
[startUpOptions setObject:CCScreenOrientationPortrait forKey:CCSetupScreenOrientation];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check under General/Deployment Info, There are checkbox options for Portrait, Upside down, Landscape left, landscape right.  Make sure your intended options are also ticked appropriately.  Also, check your "vary for traits" in your storyboard. There may be some conflict or something.  If your game was made in Unity/Unreal, you gotta check the settings there before exporting to iOS format.

Comment: Tried that. Under Deployment Info. Dont have any storyboards in my project.